# How to protect secrets properly?

Tags: api, http-headers, here-api

I am using HERE api in both frontend and backend. If I try to put my app_id and app_code into the frontend code, it will be available to anyone seeing my site.

I can try to create a domain whitelist and put my domain in this. But still, if I set the HTTP header "Referer" to my domain, I am able to access the API from any IP.

So, what do I do?

Comment: Would you please see api control access about a domain whitelist in FAQ? https://developer.here.com/faqs#access-control. Is this a solution you are looking for?

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport As I said, even if I use a domain whitelisting, my access credentials still can be abused through manual setting of HTTP header.

Answer (score 1):

## The Difference Between WHO and WHAT is Accessing the API Server

Before I dive into your problem I would like to first clear a misconception about **WHO** and **WHAT** is accessing an API server.

To better understand the differences between the **WHO** and the **WHAT** are accessing an API server, let’s use this picture:

[image: Man in the Middle Attack]

So replace the mobile app by web app, and keep following my analogy around this picture.

The Intended Communication Channel represents the web app being used as you expected, by a legit user without any malicious intentions, communicating with the API server from the browser, not using Postman or using any other tool to perform a man in the middle(MitM) attack.

The actual channel may represent several different scenarios, like a legit user with malicious intentions that may be using Curl or a tool like Postman to perform the requests, a hacker using a MitM attack tool, like MitmProxy, to understand how the communication between the web app and the API server is being done in order to be able to replay the requests or even automate attacks against the API server. Many other scenarios are possible, but we will not enumerate each one here.

I hope that by now you may already have a clue why the **WHO** and the **WHAT** are not the same, but if not it will become clear in a moment.

The **WHO** is the user of the web app that we can authenticate, authorize and identify in several ways, like using OpenID Connect or OAUTH2 flows.

> [OAUTH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)
>
> Generally, OAuth provides to clients a "secure delegated access" to server resources on behalf of a resource owner. It specifies a process for resource owners to authorize third-party access to their server resources without sharing their credentials. Designed specifically to work with Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP), OAuth essentially allows access tokens to be issued to third-party clients by an authorization server, with the approval of the resource owner. The third party then uses the access token to access the protected resources hosted by the resource server.
>
> [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/)
>
> OpenID Connect 1.0 is a simple identity layer on top of the OAuth 2.0 protocol. It allows Clients to verify the identity of the End-User based on the authentication performed by an Authorization Server, as well as to obtain basic profile information about the End-User in an interoperable and REST-like manner.

While user authentication may let the API server know **WHO** is using the API, it cannot guarantee that the requests have originated from **WHAT** you expect, the browser were your web app should be running from, with a real user.

Now we need a way to identify **WHAT** is calling the API server, and here things become more tricky than most developers may think. The **WHAT** is the thing making the request to the API server. Is it really a genuine instance of the web app, or is a bot, an automated script or an attacker manually poking around with the API server, using a tool like Postman?

For your surprise, you may end up discovering that It can be one of the legit users manipulating manually the requests or an automated script that is trying to gamify and take advantage of the service provided by the web app.

Well, to identify the **WHAT**, developers tend to resort to an API key that usually is sent in the headers of the web app. Some developers go the extra mile and compute the key at run-time in the web app, inside obfuscated javascript, thus it becomes a runtime secret, that can be reverse engineered by deobusfaction tools, and by inspecting the traffic between the web app and API server with the F12 or MitM tools.

The above write-up was extracted from an article I wrote, entitled *WHY DOES YOUR MOBILE APP NEED AN API KEY?*. While in the context of a Mobile App, the overall idea is still valid in the context of a web app. You wish you can read the article in full [here](https://blog.approov.io/why-does-your-mobile-app-need-an-api-key), that is the first article in a series of articles about API keys.

## Your Problem

> I can try to create a domain whitelist and put my domain in this. But still, if I set the HTTP header "Referer" to my domain, I am able to access the API from any IP.

So this seems to be related with using the HERE admin interface, and I cannot help you here...

> So, what do I do?
>
> I am using HERE API in both frontend and backend.

The frontend MUST always delegate access to third part APIs into a backend that is under the control of the owner of the frontend, this way you don't expose access credentials to access this third part services in your frontend.

So the difference is that now is under your direct control how you will protect against abuse of HERE API access, because you are no longer exposing to the public the HERE `api_id` and `api_code`, and access to it must be processed through your backend, where your access secrets are hidden from public pry eyes, and where you can easily monitor and throttle usage, before your bill skyrockets in the HERE API.

> If I try to put my app_id and app_code into the frontend code, it will be available to anyone seeing my site.

So to recap, the only credentials you SHOULD expose in your frontend is the ones to access your backend, the usual `api-key` and `Authorization` tokens, or whatsoever you want to name them, not the `api_id` or `api_code` to access the HERE API. This approach leaves you only with one access to protect, instead of multiple ones.

## Defending an API Server

As I already said, but want to reinforce a web app should only communicate with an API server that is under your control and any access to third part APIs services must be done by this same API server you control. This way you limit the attack surface to only one place, where you will employ as many layers of defence as what you are protecting is worth.

For an API serving a web app, you can employ several layers of dense, starting with [reCaptcha V3](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html), followed by [Web Application Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_firewall)(WAF) and finally if you can afford it a [User Behavior Analytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_behavior_analytics)(UBA) solution.

Google [reCAPTCHA V3](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html):

> reCAPTCHA is a free service that protects your website from spam and abuse. reCAPTCHA uses an advanced risk analysis engine and adaptive challenges to keep automated software from engaging in abusive activities on your site. It does this while letting your valid users pass through with ease.
>
> ...helps you detect abusive traffic on your website without any user friction. It returns a score based on the interactions with your website and provides you more flexibility to take appropriate actions.

[WAF - Web Application Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_firewall):

> A web application firewall (or WAF) filters, monitors, and blocks HTTP traffic to and from a web application. A WAF is differentiated from a regular firewall in that a WAF is able to filter the content of specific web applications while regular firewalls serve as a safety gate between servers. By inspecting HTTP traffic, it can prevent attacks stemming from web application security flaws, such as SQL injection, cross-site scripting (XSS), file inclusion, and security misconfigurations.

[UBA - User Behavior Analytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_behavior_analytics):

> User behavior analytics (UBA) as defined by Gartner is a cybersecurity process about the detection of insider threats, targeted attacks, and financial fraud. UBA solutions look at patterns of human behavior, and then apply algorithms and statistical analysis to detect meaningful anomalies from those patterns—anomalies that indicate potential threats. Instead of tracking devices or security events, UBA tracks a system's users. Big data platforms like Apache Hadoop are increasing UBA functionality by allowing them to analyze petabytes worth of data to detect insider threats and advanced persistent threats.

All these solutions work based on a negative identification model, by other words they try their best to differentiate the bad from the good by identifying what is bad, not what is good, thus they are prone to false positives, despite the advanced technology used by some of them, like machine learning and artificial intelligence.

So you may find yourself more often than not in having to relax how you block the access to the API server in order to not affect the good users. This also means that these solutions require constant monitoring to validate that the false positives are not blocking your legit users and that at the same time they are properly keeping at bay the unauthorized ones.

## Summary

Anything that runs on the client side and needs some secret to access an API can be abused in different ways and you must delegate the access to all third part APIs to a backend under your control, so that you reduce the attack surface, and at the same time protect their secrets from public pry eyes.

In the end, the solution to use in order to protect your API server must be chosen in accordance with the value of what you are trying to protect and the legal requirements for that type of data, like the GDPR regulations in Europe.

So using API keys may sound like locking the door of your home and leave the key under the mat, but not using them is liking leaving your car parked with the door closed, but the key in the ignition.

## Going the Extra Mile

[OWASP Web Top 10 Risks](https://www.owasp.org/images/7/72/OWASP_Top_10-2017_%28en%29.pdf.pdf)

> The OWASP Top 10 is a powerful awareness document for web application security. It represents a broad consensus about the most critical security risks to web applications. Project members include a variety of security experts from around the world who have shared their expertise to produce this list.