# is it safe to put here-api licence-keys, app-token & app id in android apk?

Tags: here-api

As the question suggests I wanna ask is it safe to put 
`here_maps_appid`,
`here_maps_apptoken` and
`here_maps_license_key`
in an android apk publicly in insecure way? As a security tester I wanted to ask if these can be used unauthorized?

I'm actually testing an android app that have these hardcoded and it doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: Does this thread help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55766737/how-to-protect-secrets-properly

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport Thanks this actually helped :)